# how to manage Web Push Notification in Internet explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, cross-browser, internet-explorer-11

I want to know can we disable "Deny" button in IE for Web Push Notification?

OR

If we deny permission then how could I revert permission or ask again for Allow or Deny?

In Chrome and Firefox We can change permission by clicking on left corner icon near to URL but IE doesn't provide this kind of provisioning.
Please help if you can!!!!!!

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: hi - Can you pls let me know how you implemented web push notifications in IE? Does it work in IE11 as well? Can you pls share some code snippets or pointers?

Comment: Hi, I implemented in IE11 as well but there was many limitation in IE. I think that's why people are using Push Notification in IE.

Comment: Hi, Since you have implemented it, Can you pls share me some code snippets or pointers for the same? Does it work on Edge as well?

Comment: sorry more than a year back i implemented it and I don't have code right now. Let me try to find out or create a sample for you.